# How to access/get property pages in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am creating a property page using the extension `org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages`.

In the implemented class, I need to validate some condition for the specific (myPage created) page, that I wrote in the `performOk()` method.

Even if I change the page (that means other page in the property), and click’s Ok, the original page is also validating.

But it should be validated only when I am in myPage not in other page.

`getContainer()` method having the current page. But don't know how to fetch.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking. `performOk` is always called once the user has looked at a property page regardless of which page they are on when they click OK.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have to validate some values configured in the page. But if i am in the different page those message should not come after clicking ok button. Is there any other option to do that.

Comment: You should do the validation as soon as the user changes a value on the page. Add listeners to the controls and redo the validation each time something changes.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In some case listeners will work. But in one case if user nothing selected then we need to give error message, in this case listener cant be applied. How can be handled here??

Comment: Do the validation when the page is created as well.